# SID is not showing in the frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, url, session

I turned on SID using `store>configuration>general>web>use Store ID in frontend` but it does not show in the front end. I've tried looking for solutions but all I could find is how to disable SID instead of enabling it. How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Magento version: 2.1.7

Comment: Facing the same issue on version 2.1.7, which version are you using?

Comment: @FrankGroot v2.1.7 CE